# Link error: Cannot find -l<path to library>

Tags: c++, openssl, ubuntu-14.04, kdevelop, libssl

I am developing a `C++` project in `Ubuntu` with `kDevelop` as the IDE. The project makes use of `openssl boost cryptopp` libraries. While building the project, I am getting the link error as `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a`.

As far as I know, `-l` comes along with the name of library(for e.g., -lcryptopp) and not its path. But why is `-l` is present here before the path? The specified library do exist in this path.

How can I overcome this problem? Thankyou.

EDIT:

Portion from Cmakelists.txt:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)
find_package( Boost COMPONENTS thread system date_time regex filesystem chrono)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package (OpenSSL)
include_directories(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
message("LINKED :" ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}) # ALL THE LIBRARIES ARE LISTED HERE CORECTLY
ADD_EXECUTABLE(Abc ${Abc_SRC})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Abc ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Abc ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES})

target_link_libraries(Abc ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})  
install(TARGETS Abc RUNTIME DESTINATION ./)
```

EDIT2: Screenshot added
[image: Screenshot of CMake Configuration Window in kDevelop]

Comment: Show your `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: From this "portion" of `CMakeLists.txt` I can't see you specified `-l/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a`. Also, are you sure you have installed `openssl`? Can you find it by running `locate libssl.a` ?

Comment: Yes I could locate it. As I told, the path to library is specified in cmake configuration window of kDevelop

Comment: The message command lists all the required openssl libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the library exists and you add -I"Path to your libcryptopp" to the directories that needs to be included for building , if you need to link the library with -l

eg: g++ -o targetobjects -I"Path to your libcryptopp" -lcryptopp

or else you can give the full path to the libcryptopp 
eg:  g++ -o targetobjects "path to the libcryptopp from the makefile location"

Comment: I am making use of cmake in kdevelop and building is done from the IDE itself.

Comment: have you added the include directory with include_directories()

eg : include_directories(${Path to your libcryptopp})
 target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE} ${YOUR cryptopp})

Comment: Yes.. I have done it and in the cmake configuration of the project all paths are being listed correctly.

Comment: Is that libcryptopp library available in "Path to your libcryptopp" .also if the file exists . check if there is any typo is library name in your cmake file .

Comment: NO. the problem is with libssl library. I have checked each character and nothing is wrong. :(

Comment: I specified the location by browsing it from the configuration window.

Answer (score 0):

In my practice it is best way to find does your library exist in the system is using `locate` and `ld` tools:

1. **Locate** to find a library itself on the filesystem:

   ```
   locate libssl.a
   ```

   **NOTE** that it can show a filesystem nodes of files that *DONT* exists anymore. Use `updatedb` before using `locate`.
2. `ld -lssl --verbose` to find library by linker which uses system `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable:

   ```
   :~$ ld -lssl --verbose
   attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libssl.so failed
   attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libssl.a failed
   attempt to open /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so failed
   attempt to open /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.a failed
   attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libssl.so failed
   attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libssl.a failed
   attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so failed
   attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.a failed
   attempt to open /lib64/libssl.so failed
   attempt to open /lib64/libssl.a failed
   attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so succeeded
   -lssl (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so)
   libcrypto.so.1.0.0 needed by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so
   found libcrypto.so.1.0.0 at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
   libc.so.6 needed by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so
   found libc.so.6 at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
   libdl.so.2 needed by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
   found libdl.so.2 at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
   ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 needed by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
   found ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
   ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
   ```

   You'll get this behavior when you try find it.

So, what happens when you try to find `libssl.a` actually, what does ld tool perform? You may try to investigate it by running `ld -l/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a --verbose`:

```
ld -l/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a --verbose`
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/lib/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/lib/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/lib/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/lib/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a.a failed
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a.so failed
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a.a failed
attempt to open /lib64/lib/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a.so failed
attempt to open /lib64/lib/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/lib/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/lib/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a.a failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/lib/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/lib/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/lib/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/lib/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a.a failed
attempt to open /lib/lib/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a.so failed
attempt to open /lib/lib/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/lib/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/lib/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a.a failed
ld: cannot find -l/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a
```

If you'd know what `-l` and `-L` ld-options mean you would know what it does exactly: everything after `-l` is library name you search and want to link; `-L` sets a path (appends to linker's own list during linking process) where to search your libraries.

Edit your `CMakeLists.txt` properly in order to fix this.

Comment: But from where did this `-l` come in the path?

Comment: I get the following message when executing `ld /home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a --verbose` : `attempt to open /home/anaswara/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a succeeded.   
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address`. But `ld -l/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a --verbose` says it cannot find..

Comment: Can you show **FULL** `CMakeLists.txt` ? And where this "Cmake configuration window" ? Does this window affects `CXXFLAGS` variable of the `CMakeLists.txt` ?

Comment: The cmakelists is splitted. The structure of my project is `ABCD->Abc'. The find and include portions of Cmake is written in CMAKelists.txt of ABCD and the target_link_libraries is written in that of Abc.

Comment: The configuration window can be opened from kDevelop. Project->OpenConfiguration.

Comment: I can see nothing in this window to set libraries. Can you give me a screenshot where did you specify them?

Comment: Once you have loaded the project to kDevlop using Project->Open/import Project-> <Cmakelists.txt of the project>, the configuration window will have all the needed values.

Answer (score 0):

> While building the project, I am getting the link error as /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a

An archive (`libssl.a`) is a collection of object files. As such, you use it in this instance just like any other object file. There's no need for the `-l`:

```
gcc foo.o bar.o -o baz.exe
```

In your case, something like:

```
gcc foo.o bar.o /home/anz/openssl-1.0.1j/libssl.a -o baz.exe
```

I frequently use the same techniques to ensure I'm linking against static version of libraries because its portable between Mac OS X, Linux and BSD. `-Bstatic`, `-L` and `-l` are *not* portable because OS X always links against a dynamic library if available.

In `KDevelop`, you just need to find the place where you specify additional object files (because an archive is just a collection of object files).

Comment: I am not sure frm where did this `-l` come?

Comment: @Anzz - I don't know. It was in your post. I just cited it.

Comment: yes.. It is that causes me pblm.. but not sure on how to overcome it